# Repetition of a preposition before a proper noun

Tags: usage, science, génitif

> Montrer qu'un gaz satisfaisant aux trois lois de Boyle-Mariotte, Gay-Lussac et Charles vérifie l'équation : `PVT^{-1}=Cste`.
>   Montrer aussi la réciproque.
>
> Montrer qu'un gaz satisfaisant aux trois lois de Boyle-Mariotte, de Gay-Lussac et de Charles vérifie l'équation : `PVT^{-1}=Cste`.
>   Montrer aussi la réciproque.

Quelle tournure est la plus correcte et compréhensible dans le contexte d'un sujet ?

Comment: "*un gaz satisfaisant aux trois lois*" n'est pas correct. *Satisfaisant les trois lois* peut-être ? Ou *conforme aux trois lois*.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Tournure tirée par un livre de Thermodynamique (en français) chez de boeck !

Comment: @TeleportingGoat on satisfait à une obligation, à une injonction, etc. Satisfaire peut avoir un objet direct ou indirect et les deux options me semblent possibles ici, quoique la première fait très littéraire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les deux tournures sont correctes et compréhensibles.

La première est cependant plus aérée et moins lourde, donc plus agréable à lire.